# How to 'Sync' or catch-up a named branch till a particular revision of default

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've a named branch in my Mercurial repository which I'd like to 'sync' or bring upto date with default but **till a particular revision** of default branch (*not the tip*).

 I already know how to 'Sync a named Branch' with merging default into it. However, I'm unable to find a way to sync till only a particular revision of default.

**EDIT**: 

  Here is what I wanted to achieve, explained through a graph:


ci0
|
|
ci1*..\ (feature branch)
|........\
|.........\
ci2*.....\
|...........\
|............\
ci3*........\
|...............\
|................\
ci4*----------O(*merge 'default' until ci4, i.e. ci2-4, into 'feature' branch*)
|
|
ci5*
|
ci6*
|
ci7* (tip)


 Thank you in advance.

Comment: You definitely should re-consider your attitude, probably re-read the docs for merge and then consider to appologize to LazyBadger ;)
Take into account that you can merge any arbitrary revision, not just tip.

Comment: My apologies. I suppose I had gotten slightly confused when I read the Merge info at : https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Merge. However, got better clarity of what I wanted to achieve from this resource: http://www.draketo.de/light/english/mercurial/complete-branching-strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge with a specific changeset you would basically do:

```
hg update feature-branch
hg merge changeset-revno-on-default-branch
```

There really is no magic here.

To merge the entire default branch into your feature branch you would just specify `default` in the merge command above but you can also just specify the revision number or hash of the specific changeset you want to merge with.

Example:

```
hg update feature-branch
hg merge ci4
```

(assuming `ci4` is the revision number or hash of the changeset you want to merge with, specific commands would be either something like `hg merge abb387187` or `hg merge 42`)

If you're using TortoiseHg (or *probably* any other visual tool for Mercurial) you would first update to the branch you want to merge into, then right-click the specific changeset you want to merge into it. A merge will always attempt to merge the history *up to that point* and not just the specific changeset you right-click on.

If you *only* want a specific changeset you are looking for the `graft` command but I mention this only for completeness, not as a direct answer to your question.

Comment: sorry, I had updated the question, because I had gotten it to solve using the same way what you've mentioned in your example above.(It took some time to understand the Merge manual of Mercurial which confused me initially :| )
Thanks for your answer which is correct in this context, so I'll mark it correct for this question.